# Zooming the mapview

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, zooming

I am doing an app based on mapview. I am getting the location(place) and converting it to co-ordinates. Using this, I am zooming into the exact location of the place specified.

But the problem I am facing is that,
 If I am specifying just the street name or the city name or the state name or the country name the zoom level is always the same. (The zoomlevel is always the same as that of the street.)
If I am just specifying just the country name, the zoom level should be of the country level and not zooming right into any random street of the country.

Here is the code I have used in zooming.

```
-(void)zoomToFitMapAnnotations:(MKMapView*)mapViews
{
if([mapViews.annotations count] == 0)
    return;

CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoordinate;
topLeftCoordinate.latitude = -90;
topLeftCoordinate.longitude = 180;

CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoord;
bottomRightCoord.latitude = 90;
bottomRightCoord.longitude = -180;

for(SJAddressAnnotation* annotation in mapViews.annotations)
{
    topLeftCoordinate.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoordinate.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    topLeftCoordinate.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);

    bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
}

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = topLeftCoordinate.latitude - (topLeftCoordinate.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5;
region.center.longitude = topLeftCoordinate.longitude + (bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoordinate.longitude) * 0.5;
region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCoordinate.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.1; // Add a little extra space on the sides
region.span.longitudeDelta = fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoordinate.longitude) * 1.1; // Add a little extra space on the sides

region = [mapView regionThatFits:region];
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

I have tried changing the span level unsuccessfully. Needs help in this case.

Comment: your final region is determined by annotation.coordinate only. which (coordinates) does not contain any information about whether annotation is city, state or country.

Comment: How could I set the co-ordinates based on city/country?

Comment: Firstly annotations coordinate are just coordinate of single location. It cannot contain information on size of thing you are trying to represent through annotations. If you want to store size information you will have to use separate parameter in annotations. Secondly there is no standard size for country, city or street. for example consider countries like Russia and Monaco.  From where are you getting annotations? through web server or what? Or they are defined by you?

Comment: So what I am doing now, is it considered a standard way to display maps

Comment: When you have more than 1 annotations to display you can find the MKMaprect that contains them and set it as a region. but if you have only one annotation to display then you will have to set region span manually to some constant value.

Comment: When it is more than one annotation, its working just fine according to requirements(loads a view with all contacts). Its only when a single contact is displayed, that I am finding it a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said earlier there is problem with one annotation. If you are retrieving the places from Google search then with each place they give approximate level of zoom(depending upon whether it is country/city). you can try by typing `http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=asia&output=json` in your browser. you can try different entries by replacing asia with china or newyork etc. Look at the `Accuracy` attribute of response in browser. It will be 0 for continents, 1 for countries etc.

If you have created annotations by yourself then you can attach a parameter to it which will relate to zoomlevel.

```
@interface AddressAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation> {
double zoomLevel;
}
@property(readwrite,nonatomic) double zoomLevel ;
@end




 @implementation AddressAnnotation
    @synthesize zoomLevel;
    -(void)setZoomLevel (double) parameter
    {
    self.zoomLevel = parameter;
    }
@end
```

and finally assuming annot is your annotation then

```
  [annot setZoomLevel: .1]; //instead of .1 you can set different values
```

when you are displaying this annotation set region center as annotation coordinate and set span as annotation.zoomLevel.

```
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = annotation.coordinate.latitude;
region.center.longitude = annotation.coordinate.longitude;
region.span.latitudeDelta = annotation.zoomLevel;
region.span.longitudeDelta = annotation.zoomLevel;
```